# Is Tor 3.5 better or 0.2.4.20?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Which version is better to be used ?
Because both of them are released to be used as stable versions but I don't know. I expect not Tor 3.5 because still first release for this type of Tor. Give me any comments or viewpoints that could increase my information.

Comment: You are confusing two different packages with Tor. The **Tor Browser Bundle** (TBB) is currently in version 3.5, the standalone **Tor** is in version 0.2.4.20. TBB is easy to use package with preconfigured web browser, Tor is for more advanced users. --- Please edit your question to make clear if you are asking about TBB versus Tor package or something else.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're confusing the Tor Browser Bundle (currently at 3.5) with the Tor executable (currently in the 0.2.4.x series).

The Tor Browser Bundle (version 3.5) contains, as part of it, an automatically configured version of the Tor executable (0.2.4 series).

You most likely want the Tor Browser Bundle, unless you're wanting to take advantage of more advanced features.

Comment: yes am very confused could you tell me what to use and what difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you are new to Tor, it may be best to use Tor browser bundle. As of today the newest version of TBB is 3.6.2. One additional benefit of TBB is that many people use that, and it becomes difficult to find you among all others. In technical terms it is called fingerprinting. The larger the number of users who use exactly same version of an identical software, the more difficult it becomes to distinguish them from each other.